# Position of UIImageView during an animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview

Today I make a shoot em up game without `SpriteKit`
And I have a problem for check `UIImageView` position during an animation.

**Code I have tried:**

```
@IBAction func MoveTDButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        animationForPlane = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, curve: .easeIn, animations: {
            if sender.tag == 1 {
                self.ship.center.x = sender.frame.origin.x + sender.frame.size.width - (self.ship.frame.size.width / 2)
                self.ship.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "shipright")
                print(self.ship.center.x)
            }else{
                self.ship.center.x = sender.frame.origin.x + (self.ship.frame.size.width / 2)
                self.ship.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "shipleft")
                print(self.ship.center.x)
            }
        })
        animationForPlane.startAnimation()
    }

    private func autoshoot(_ imgShip :UIImageView, _ imgBullet :UIImageView){
        var t: TimeInterval!
        t = 0.2
        //var hauteur = self.view.frame.maxY
        if let duration = t {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                imgBullet.center.y = 10
                imgBullet.center.x = self.ship.center.x
            }, completion: { (true) in
                imgBullet.center.x = self.ship.center.x
                imgBullet.center.y = imgShip.center.y
                //checkPosEnemy(img, hauteur: hauteur)
                self.autoshoot(imgShip, imgBullet)
            })
        }

    }
```

The function `MoveTDButton` it's for move my ship by button (left and right) with animation for the slide.
And, auto shoot function for shoot ^^

**Problem :**

When I click on a button for move my ship, position is set at the end of animation and not during.
So my bullet is not shoot at the ship's position but at the end of animation.

Comment: Considering you are coding a game and not some static animations, should you not instead update the position of the ship every frame by the player's current action to check for other activities such as getting hit by enemies or collision with terrain? That will enable you to also use that position to place your bullets for shooting.

Comment: I agree with Ben Ong. Game programming best practices is to follow the frame cycle and update the positions of your objects frame by frame. SpriteKit has the game cycle already implemented for this purpose. I recommend to migrate to spriteKit.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you Use SpriteKit or similar frameworks.

However to answer to your question you can try :

`imgBullet.center.x = self.ship.layer.presentation()!.position`
instead of 
`imgBullet.center.x = self.ship.center.x`